# How do I create a space between my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my banner but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get an empty space between my logo and login links. Heres what I have so far: imgur.com/a/2pfjI
 I feel like I'm close but I cannot work it out!!

Heres the HTML: https://pastebin.com/Z1v3UdDB
Heres my CSS: https://pastebin.com/SnjH8jZj

I want to have my logo on the left, two links beside that and then a space with login/sign up on the far right, almost flush with the edge of the page. Kinda like this

Logo......Link 1 | Link 2..............space here......................Login/Sign Up

Thanks in advance!
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Make a working example jsfiddle with your code. You can use the code snippet button right in your question

Comment: have you ever tried `float:left` or `float:right`?

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate and does not contain a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Per closure rules: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* Voting to close for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn with this example. This how I set up my headers with flexbox. Key changes: using box-sizing: border-box, flexbox, and margin: auto to control position on flexed item.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #181926;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: rgb(101, 172, 255);
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0 auto 0 100px;

}
.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
}

.separator {
  margin: 0 10px;;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="browse.php">Browse</a></li>
              <span class="separator">|</span>
                <li><a href="create.php">Create</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
           <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am trying to achieve, I'll have a play around, from the other comments flexboxes appear to be the solution, thank you for your response!

Comment: You got it, yea definitely mess around with that .nav margin and maybe padding on the other sections. With box-sizing: border-box; you can add padding without adding to the width and worrying about overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="header flex">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/logo.png"></a>
        <ul class="nav flex">
            <li><a href="browse.php">Browse</a> | <a href="create.php">Create</a> </li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

No need for all the extra divs.

Added display flex to the `.header` and the `ul`. Kept `display:flex` as its own class for clarity so you can see where I added it in the html.

Gave the `ul` a width of 100%.

Then added `justify-content: space-between` to the `ul`.

Here is a bin to preview https://jsbin.com/cepopi/edit?html,css,output

---

- This is probably the best starting point for learning more about flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- This is a great game to play for practice: http://flexboxfroggy.com/
- And here is a fantastic free course if you have the time and are serious: https://flexbox.io/

Comment: Great thank you for this, all the responses are fairly similar so thank you for shining some light on this!

Comment: No worries. Added some useful links for getting into flexbox. Word of caution, flexbox is great but doesn't play well with ie9 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can link bootstrap in your head section like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

then try using

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item" id="logo">
     <a class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" href="index.php"><img src="imgs/logo.png"></a>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" href="browse.php">Browse</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" href="create.php">Create</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" href="login.php">Login</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then in css

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
```

try that..